# Target a specific element inside $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make the id popMessage be appened only in the 1st class pop

this is the jquery code

```
$(".list-group-item").mouseenter(function(){
  if($(this).textContent = "Property damage" )
  {
    $(".pop").append(" <div id='popMessage'><b>Appended text</b><img id='theImg' src='https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/181436-200.png'/></div>")
  }
});
```

this is the html body

```
<li class="list-group-item">Property damage<div class= "pop"></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Bodily injury<div class= "pop"></div></li>
```

The contents of the li are extracted from an ng-repeat (angularjs)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first or http://api.jquery.com/first-selector.

Comment: Well  `=` is assignment, not a comparison, next jQuery does not have a textContent property.

Comment: `1st class pop` do you mean the `.pop` that belongs to the `list-group-item` you mouse entered, as using `:first` would always select the `li -> Property damage"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code. What you need to do is fix those so you can target the correct element. You have an assignment in your if statement. You are also looking for textContent which is not part of jQuery. And you are selecting all of the `.pop` elements, not the one in the current li being hovered.

```js
$(".list-group-item").mouseenter(function(){
  var li = $(this)  //reference the element
  if(li.text() === "Property damage" ) {  //notice here it uses text and correct comparison
    li.find(".pop").append(" <div id='popMessage'><b>Appended text</b><img id='theImg' src='https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/181436-200.png'/></div>")  //now we find the pop element in the li that is hovered
  }
});

$(".list-group-item").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find(".pop").empty()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="list-group-item">Property damage<div class= "pop"></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Bodily injury<div class= "pop"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Now in the end using text is a bad idea. You would be better off with a class, data-attribute, or id.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very big help. I'm really not an expert in Jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to append to the first and you can make a validation to avoid appending it several times... like the example.

```js
$(".list-group-item:first").mouseenter(function(){
  if(!$(this).find('#popMessage').length)
  {
    $(".pop:first").append(" <div id='popMessage'><b>Appended text</b><img id='theImg' src='https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/181436-200.png'/></div>")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-group-item">Property damage<div class= "pop"></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item">Bodily injury<div class= "pop"></div></li>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(this).find('.pop').append(" <div id='popMessage'><b>Appended text</b><img id='theImg' src='https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/181436-200.png'/></div>")
```

Try it